# High CPU usage when using pebbe zmq proxy at high message rates

Tags: sockets, go, arm, zeromq, message-passing

I am currently experimenting with ZMQ as a possible message broker for IPCs.
**Version -> ZMQv4**
I am using [pebbe ZMQ](https://github.com/pebbe/zmq4) , a go library over zmq's C library and performing tests.

I am rate testing it with a message rate of 1500 messages/sec and 10000 messages/sec.

I am using an XPUB-XSUB architecture with a publisher and subscriber connected to the proxy.

I understand the go library is just a wrapper hence for actual sending and receiving of messages c-go calls are involved.

I am experimenting this on a device with arm architecture.
I see almost 40-50% CPU usage (100% is ~1GB with ~900MB on RAM and ~100MB on swap memory) for message passing on the proxy itself @rate of 1500 messages/sec.

I am not sure if this is okay or high usage. Not really sure what to use as a yard stick here.

I ran a profiling test and I see that runtime cgocall and runtime _ExternalCode is taking most of the CPU.
Have attached the image of the profile graph (not sure how to upload an SVG).

[image]

I am trying to understand or reduce the CPU usage.
Based on this profile I don't think there is much I can do.
Is there a way to reduce CPU due to C Go calls and the external code block shown in the profile.
Not really done profiling before, so may not know many things.

***Code to reproduce example:***

**ZMQ Broker**

```
import (
    "fmt"

    zmq "github.com/pebbe/zmq4"
    "github.com/pkg/profile"
)

func main() {
    defer profile.Start(profile.CPUProfile, profile.ProfilePath(".")).Stop()
    fmt.Println("Setting up XSUB socket")
    subscriberSocket, err := zmq.NewSocket(zmq.XSUB)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error when creating XSUB socket -> ", err)
    }
    defer subscriberSocket.Close()

    err = subscriberSocket.Bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:8101")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error when binding XSUB socket -> ", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Succesfully accepting incoming connections on XSUB socket")
    }

    fmt.Println("Setting up XPUB socket")

    publisherSocket, err := zmq.NewSocket(zmq.XPUB)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error when creating XPUB socket -> ", err)
    }
    defer publisherSocket.Close()

    err = publisherSocket.Bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:8100")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error when binding XPUB socket -> ", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Succesfully accepting incoming connections on XPUB socket")
    }

    err = zmq.Proxy(publisherSocket, subscriberSocket, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to start the XPUB XSUB broker -> ", err)
    }
}
```

**Publisher**:

```
import (
    "time"

    zmq "github.com/pebbe/zmq4"

    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    publisher, err := zmq.NewSocket(zmq.PUB)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error when connecting to a pub socket -> ", err)
    }

    defer publisher.Close()

    err = publisher.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:8101")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error when connecting to a pub socket -> ", err)
    }

    for range time.Tick(time.Microsecond * 500) {
        sendToAll(publisher)
    }
}

func sendToAll(pub *zmq.Socket) {
    var message = "topicA test"
    _, err := pub.Send(message, zmq.DONTWAIT)
    if err != nil {
        println("error when sending message-> ", err)
    }
}
```

**Subscriber**

```
import (
    "os"
    "strconv"

    zmq "github.com/pebbe/zmq4"

    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    //  Socket to talk to server
    fmt.Println("Collecting updates from broker...")
    subscriber, err := zmq.NewSocket(zmq.SUB)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error when opening new socket to SUB -> ", err)
    }
    defer subscriber.Close()
    err = subscriber.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:8100")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error when connecting to XSUB port -> ", err)
    }

    err = subscriber.SetSubscribe("topicA ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error when setting subscription filter -> ", err)
    }
    i := 0
    for {
        msg, err := subscriber.Recv(0)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error when reciveing subscription info -> ", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        i += 1
        fmt.Println(msg + "\n -> count is" + strconv.Itoa(i))
    }
}
```

**The parameters I am using to cross-compile is:**
Not sure if how this is configured matters for performance

```
#!/bin/bash

ARM_PREFIX="arm-linux-androideabi-" 

TOOLCHAIN_PATH="/home/NDK/arm"

CC="${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/bin/${ARM_PREFIX}gcc" \
CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon" \
GOOS=android \
GOARCH=arm \
GOARM=7 \
CGO_ENABLED=1 \
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/lib/pkgconfig" \
go build -o test
```

Possible Proxy Code(What I think should be there) even with this the CPU is similar so I am assuming this is almost same as what the library implements. Not sure.

```
for {
    // this will block forever till an event occurs
    sockets, err := poller.Poll(-1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error when establishing xpubsub poller")
    }
    for _, socket := range sockets {
        switch s := socket.Socket; s {
        case publisherSocket:
            msg, err := s.Recv(0)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("error when recieving on publisherSocket")
            }
            subscriberSocket.Send(msg, zmq.DONTWAIT)
        case subscriberSocket:
            msg, err := s.Recv(0)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("error when recieving on subscribersocket")
            }
            publisherSocket.Send(msg, zmq.DONTWAIT)
        }
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to reduce CPU due to C Go calls and the external code?
2. I expected not this high CPU utilisation as the proxy is a blocking poller, that blocks until an event is triggered. Possible I am wrong here as microsecond does seem like a very high frequency , not sure if this is high for the CPU.
3. Appreciate pointers and things to consider when doing performance tuning of this kind.

Comment: Why not use this: https://github.com/go-zeromq/zmq4? I saw xpub-xsub support is there.